# I want to schedule task at particular time for different day(Monday, Tuesday, etc) in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, scheduled-tasks, alarmmanager

Currently I am working on **BroadcastReceiver, Service & AlarmManager** in Android to developed one of functionality in my project. I need to schedule some task at particular time on particular day.

For E.g :-

**Monday - 09:00 AM & 05:00 PM**

**Tuesday - 09:00 AM & 05:00 PM**

**Wednesday - 09:00 AM & 05:00 PM**

**Thursday - 09:00 AM & 05:00 PM**

**Friday - 09:00 AM & 05:00 PM**

**Saturday - 10:00 AM & 10:00 PM**

**Sunday - 10:00 AM & 10:00 PM**

---

**What i have done till now is created one activity & broadcastreceiver. On click of button, after every 60seconds broadcast receiver will be called. Here is my code snippet. But i want to schedule my task according to the week that i have described above. Can anyone please kindly help me how can i schedule the task like above.**

**Code :-**

```
public class AlarmDemoActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button buttonStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
        buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                        MyScheduledReceiver.class);

                PendingIntent pendingIntent
                = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),
                        0, myIntent, 0);

                AlarmManager alarmManager
                = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
                long interval = 60 * 1000; //
                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        calendar.getTimeInMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
                finish();
            }});
    }
}
```

**BroadcastReceiver :-**

```
public class MyScheduledReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /*Intent scheduledIntent = new Intent(context, MyScheduledActivity.class);
        scheduledIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(scheduledIntent);*/

        System.out.println("Make Phone Silent");
    }

}
```

All suggestion and tips are welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will give the idea for this at a very high level.You will have to figure out the coding your self:

1.Save the user preferences in shared preferences(which I presume you are already doing)

2.Schedule the first alarm using the set method of Alarm Manager 
[Refer this for details on this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29).

3.When that alarm goes off,again schedule the next alarm using the next time period  in Shared Preferences,again using the set method

Comment: Yeah.It should work.If it does ,please mark this as an answer.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call it every 60 seconds, you can set the time when it should be fired into an alarm using your calendar instance and setting the correct dates, so alarm manager will fire the broadcast intent at specified dates and times.

Beware that if the phone is turned of the alarm manager will be reset so you have to store the alarms in any persistent storage and register a broadcast receiver for the BOOT_COMPLETED action to restore the alarms.

You can test with small intervals so you won't have to wait the whole day :)

Comment: I am not using 60 seconds. I added snippet that i have done that much thing right now. But i want to schedule the task for whole week twice in a day at particular time.

Comment: Can you tell me how can i schedule multiple task for different date and time. I am done with single one but not for multiple. If you know please kindly help me,

Comment: I think that you have to create a different PendingIntent for each alarm you want to schedule and set each of them using alarmManager.set(...)